# Wake on Lan configure port

Tags: wakeonlan

I was just wondering if there was a way to change the port that WakeOnLan is configured on (default port 9)?

I'm using 64bit Ubuntu 13.04.

I figured worst case I can route it using iptables from a different port to port 9, but if I can configure the port it's a cleaner solution.

Thanks in advance.

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone viewing the post I ended up just routing the requests using iptables:

Something like 
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d 192.168.0.12 --dport 14000 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.12:9`

with port 14000 forwarded on my router allowed me to use WoL over the internet on port 14000.